# SQL Selecting based on criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my attempts to create the following query in MS Access 2016, I have tried to wrap my head around this but seem to have come short.
My goal is to perform the following: "List the name and total number of years of experience of each coach of the Tigers who has 15 or more years experience."
Below are the 3 different tables: TEAM, COACH, WORK EXPERIENCE. 
What seems to be causing me the biggest issue is the counting all of the work experience that the coach has.

Expected Result from Query should yield:

COACH NAME | TOTAL NUMBER OF YRS EXPERIENCE

ADAMS | 25

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

Comment: You need to include ALL experience regardless of where acquired but only view the Tigers coaches?

Comment: Most people here want sample data as formatted text, not images. And don't forget to specify the expected result as well.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

#### Query1: SumExp

```
SELECT Sum(WorkExperience.WEXP_Yrs) AS SumOfWEXP_Yrs, WorkExperience.CoachNum
FROM WorkExperience
GROUP BY WorkExperience.CoachNum;
```

#### Query2:

```
SELECT WorkExperience.TeamNum, Coach.CoachName, SumExp.SumOfWEXP_Yrs
FROM 
    Coach INNER JOIN 
    (
        SumExp INNER JOIN 
        (
            Team INNER JOIN WorkExperience 
            ON Team.TeamNum = WorkExperience.TeamNum
        )
        ON SumExp.CoachNum = WorkExperience.CoachNum
    )
    ON Coach.CoachNum = SumExp.CoachNum
WHERE 
    WorkExperience.TeamNum = 24;
```

#### All in One:

```
SELECT WorkExperience.TeamNum, Coach.CoachName, SumExp.SumOfWEXP_Yrs
FROM 
    Coach INNER JOIN
    (
        (
            SELECT Sum(WorkExperience.WEXP_Yrs) AS SumOfWEXP_Yrs, WorkExperience.CoachNum
            FROM WorkExperience
            GROUP BY WorkExperience.CoachNum
        ) AS SumExp 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            Team INNER JOIN WorkExperience 
            ON Team.TeamNum = WorkExperience.TeamNum
        ) 
        ON SumExp.CoachNum = WorkExperience.CoachNum
    )
    ON Coach.CoachNum = SumExp.CoachNum
WHERE 
    WorkExperience.TeamNum = 24;
```

Comment: Thank you! My issue was that I was trying to use the code from Query 1 (SumExp) within Query 2 in turn I had them reversed.